# UIViewController with UITableViews and UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

previously I had a `UITableViewController` with a `UISearchBar` and it was showing up at the top by using `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;`

Now I had to redo some things and ended up with a `UIViewController` which shows 2 `UITableView's`. I wanted the upper one to show the search bar but now it's not being shown.

Now I'm using `[MyView setTableHeaderView:searchBar];` in `viewDidLoad` Method to add the searchBar to the TableView.

In the `UIViewController` the code is almost the same as in the `UITableView` (searchbar initialized and frame created as well as tableview initialized)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Idea behind all this to have a list in the upper tableview (including search bar) and another uitableview where I can choose some filtering options.

```
(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    searchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    LexikonView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 337) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    LexikonView.dataSource = self;
    LexikonView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:LexikonView];

    FilterView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 381, 320, 0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    //FilterView.dataSource = self;
    //FilterView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:FilterView];
}
return self;
}

(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib

searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;

searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

[LexikonView setTableHeaderView:searchBar];
}
```

For now I just want the searchbar to work again (as it did using a uitableviewcontroller). If I reduce the size of the upper tableview I only see empty space. I added a UISearchBar in IB and voilá there it is, but the delegate methods are not called.
And yes I want the searchbar to be always visible at the top of the tableview

Comment: Add full code, we can't guess!

Comment: 1) You have now 2 UITableView's in one view ? 2) Can you add more code please ?

Comment: I think you should use 1 UITableView with 2 sections, if that helps you achieve what you want.

The reason is that If you're uIViewController is a Search bar and tableview delegate/datasource then you might run into issues. Although I am not entirely sure how you are doing it from your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `TableView` with a `SearchBar` that is always visible right?  If this is the case, you just need to add a `TableView` to a `ViewController` and leave room at the top for the `SearchBar`.  Add the `SearchBar` independently of the TableView.  I have a post that shows how this is done and also gives you some direction for really fast searching of the backing data for the `TableView`.

If this isn't what you are after, please be a little more specific in what your goals are here.  Also please post the code you are using to try to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: I actually wanted to use a SearchDisplayController. Even with your code I can't get the searchbar to work. Have you got a working project?

Comment: Yes - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3660978/Objects.zip  Lots of other stuff in there too, the part you are interested in will be the TableView scenes.  I will leave that project available for the next 24 hrs.  Please comment back when you have downloaded it.

Comment: I noticed that the searchbar is now floating on top of the tableview, so that it's always visible. Any way to move it together with the tableview?

Comment: Yes.  Just move the SearchBar to the TableView's view instead of the ViewControllers root view.

Comment: You mean in IB? Or can I do it within code as well? Was trying [self.myuppertableview setTableHeaderView:mySearchBar]; but won't do.

Comment: In IB.  You can do this in code as well (create the frame for the SearchBar view, add a SearchBar to this view and then add that to the TableView's view, but it is much easier in IB.